# 'Missing Focus scope.' Using input text

Tags: dart, flutter

I try build a form using Flutter, I have my own StatefulWidget that return a Form with 2 Input (I try with TextField too) and a DropdownButton.

When I executed the second Input show this error: 'Missing Focus scope.'

The code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ContactFormView extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  CreateFormViewState createState() => new CreateFormViewState();

}

class CreateFormViewState extends State<ContactFormView> {

  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Input(
                    labelText: 'First Name',
                    onChanged: (InputValue value) {
                      // Logic here
                    }
                ),
                new Input(
                    labelText: 'Last Name',
                    onChanged: (InputValue value) {
                      // Logic here
                    }
                ),
                new RaisedButton(
                    child: new Text('SUBMIT'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      // Logic here
                    },
                )
              ]
          )
      )
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi! Can you please add some source? That might help us help you. Thanks!

Comment: Oh yes, no problem

Comment: Did a test with the latest Flutter version (Framework revision 9adf1bf1b6 (3 hours ago), 2017-03-22 10:38:00, Engine revision 6b9eda4a40). Cannot reproduce the behavior with the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the problem was fixed on next updates. Right now, you can use this widget without problems. https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Form-class.html